# Java login system method

Tags: java

Have almost got this login system in Java to work, but am having trouble with this method:

```
public void Register() {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Register? (Y/ N)\n");
    String N = sc.nextLine();

    if ("N".equals(N)) {
        Login();
    } else {
        String Y = sc.nextLine();
        if ("Y".equals(Y)) {
        System.out.print("Email address: ");
        String string = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Password: ");

        String string2 = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.print("\n\n");
        new Products().search();
        }
    }

}
```

Entering "N" works perfectly in the if section, but "Y" needs to be entered twice before the else section works (I understand why it doesn't work).

Its something simple I know, but any clue as to how to get it to work?

Appreciate any help...

Comment: Please please please: never name variables N or Y. Use name the mean something to *human* readers. Such as: `inputFromUser`. Just N N N.

Comment: step-by-step debugging is your best friend....

Comment: As the best coding practices, please rename your variables to more intuitive names. Like     String userInput = sc.nextLine();         String emailId = sc.nextLine(); and so on.

Answer (score 5):

Here

```
String Y = sc.nextLine();
```

you are reading in another line of input. You want to compare the *same* line of input you already read, which you stored in a variable called `N`. It will be clearer if you give it a better name.

```
String line = sc.nextLine();

if ("N".equals(line)) {
    Login();
} else if ("Y".equals(line)) {
    System.out.print("Email address: ");
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks this was what I was looking for

Answer (score 3):

This
`String N = sc.nextLine();`
Again This

> String Y = sc.nextLine();

No need to use the input method twice

Change the variable name to something meaningful

Try it this way

It will surely work..

```
public void Register() {
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Register? (Y/ N)\n");
String input = sc.nextLine();

if ("N".equals(input)) {
    Login();
} else {
    // removed 'String Y = sc.nextLine();'
    if ("Y".equals(input)) {
    System.out.print("Email address: ");
    String string = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Password: ");

    String string2 = sc.nextLine();

    System.out.print("\n\n");
    new Products().search();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the second `nextLine`. Keep using the `String N` (maybe rename it to input) and keep checking that for `Y`.

Answer (score 1):

If you type `Y` it will be saved in `N` variable, it will go in the `else` section and here you're asking again the user, you don't need to

You have to take the input and test it, without knowing its N or Y

```
String choice = sc.nextLine();

if ("N".equals(choice)) {
    Login();
} else if("Y".equals(choice)){      
    System.out.print("Email address: ");
    String string = sc.nextLine();
    ...       
}else{
     System.out.println("Wrong choice");
}
```

Also

- give more significant names to your variable, no `string, string2` but `email, pwd`
- methods name have to start in `lowerCaser`  : `Login()` >> `login()`